# Admob Reward Video Ads don't work with test devices

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad, video-ads

We want to integrate Reward Video Ads in our app (https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/rewarded-video).
The ads work great if we don't provide the test device. However, if we do, we receive `error code 0` aka `ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR`, so the execution goes through `onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad`.

Is this something somebody else has encountered?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_ad);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, APP_ID);

    mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("C67A1A9F2F19699874B7718074819FF9") // Test devices don't work work with rewarded video ads.
            .build();
    mAd.loadAd(AD_UNIT_ID, adRequest);
} 

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I revisited this in November 2017 and the test device flag DOES now work with rewarded video Ads.

You can't use test devices for rewarded video, from this forum  [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/k-kVwVu2XBc):

"For Reward Videos, the following are our test Ad Unit ID:

iOS - ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313

Android - ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917

Note that Reward Video Ad Unit IDs are platform specific"

Comment: Thank your for the answer. 
So we have to do the following:

For Reward Videos, the following are our test Ad Unit ID
iOS - ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313
Android - ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917

Please update your answer with this data so that anyone can see the full answer.